# GIT clone branch to older commit in another directory

Tags: git, repo

I have 2 directories of the same project, let call them directories A and B.

These two folder were cloned from a master git repo in another location, so they both started out with the same git repo commit.

Now A stayed with the original code and fixed a few minor bugs, and commited the changes, so A git branch looks like this:

```
A: (original)-(bug fix 1) - (bug fix 2) - (bug fix 3)
```

While B, I decided to change the look of the application but I havent commited yet. so B git branch looks like this:

```
B: (original)
```

What I would like to do is merge these 2 git repos from the original clone so I can have the following:

```
A: (original)-(bug fix 1) - (bug fix 2) - (bug fix 3)--------(merge both)

           \                                                    /
branch B:   \ -----------------(New version look) -------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can push back to that repo, but you don't want to push `B`, you can:

- go to your A local clone
- add the B local clone as a remote:

  ```
  git remote add repoB ../B
  ```
- fetch and merge:

  ```
  git fetch repoB
  git checkout A
  git merge repoB/B
  ```

Comment: thank you for your response! would i have to push back to the original when the git was cloned? since they are technically both the same git one just has been worked on already

Comment: @paul590 no need for worktree in your case: you already have the same repo cloned twice. My point is: one local repo can use the other local repo as remote in order to fetch and merge your commits. Once that merge is done, you can then push back to your actual remote repo

Comment: @paul590 Again, you really don't need worktree here.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am currently working with this solution, just to make sure I understand the steps, we are first creating a new remote on a new folder location with git remote add repoB path/B?, then we pull the current repository from B into A? then we swtich the git look to A and merge the repo we just pulled form B with the path/B remote we just created? so now the remote of path/B will hold the same value as B repository? what if later on I decide my path/B remote updates are what I want and I want to merge with A would it be as simple as merge A B?

Comment: @paul590 yes, creating a ne remote is just adding a reference to B from A. That allows you to fetch B history into A, stored into the remotes/repoB namespace. Later on, you can fetch again, and merge repoB/B again.

Comment: Awesome thank you for your quick response! one last question, when you mention repoB this is the new repo we just created? I got a little confused when you say to add it and then fetch repoB? also for the merge it says repoB/B do you mean repoB that we created and B refers to the /project/projectB.git path?

Comment: @paul590 No it is just the name of the remote which points to your other local repo: you could name it xxx, but repoB makes it clearer.

Comment: I got it thank you for your help this is definitely what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

> Hello I have 2 directories of the same project, let call them directories A and B. These two folder were cloned from a master git repo in another location,

Instead of cloning the repositories use

---

## ***`git worktree`***

Git worktree was introduced in 2007 under the `contrib` folder in git repo and was called `new-workdir`. In git v2.5 is was renamed to `worktree`.

The most simple syntax is this:

```
git worktree add <second path>/<branch name>
```

will create another folder on your computer which allow you to work on different **branches** simultaneously.

`git worktree` will create 2 separate working folders separated from each other while pointing to the same repository.

This will allow you do to any experimentals on the new worktree without having any effect on the repository itself. In the attached image you can see that there are **2 separate** working folder but both of them are using a single repo and share the content.

Here is a sample on how to create new worktree and what is the result of it:

[image]

> What I would like to do is merge these 2 git repos from the original clone so I can have the following...

Now since you are working on the same repository you can **`merge`**,**`cherry-pick`** without pulling or pushing to the remote since you dont need to use the remote.
**its all local !!!**

Comment: this is awesome thank you for your response! I do have a couple of questions, since I already had created my two separate folders manually without using any git commands, would I need to merge them first and then create the worktree? or should I create it first then copy the files I already worked on and commit them onto the new branch? also what if in the future I decide to push this to the remote git?

Comment: Since you already have the 2 folder simply create the first one and than copy the content into the desired branch. The advantage of this is that you are working on a single repo and can share branches and commits without the need to clone it multiple times. you can create as many worktree as you wish.

Comment: Thank you again, I tried creating the worktree using the git worktree <path>/<branch> but I am unable to find this new directory, I followed the same format in your example /tmp/a and I am not seeing it on my project folder. or i apologize if I mis understoof and this just creates a branch in git and I have to create the folder manually?

Comment: type any folder you want ang go into it. if u use tmp it might be deleted on next login

Comment: I did the following: git worktree add /branch/update after I tried accessing this by doing on the same folder where my git repo is cd /branch/update but no luck, however I do see that update has been created but not the folder, any thoughts? or woul branch have been created in the temp folder anyways?